# How to set part of text to bold when using AlertDialog.setMessage() in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

How to set part of text to Bold when using `AlertDialog`'s `setMessage()`? Adding `<b>` and `</b>` to my `String` doesn't work.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You need to use `Html.fromHtml()` too. For example:

```java
AlertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Hello "+"<b>"+"World"+"</b>"));
```

**Update:**
Looks like [`Html.fromHtml(String source)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) has been deprecated in the Latest Android Nougat version. Although deprecation doesn't mean that you need to change your code now, but it's a good practice to remove deprecated code from your app as soon as possible.
The replacement is [`Html.fromHtml(String source, int flags)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)). You just need to add an additional parameter mentioning a flag.

```java
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   AlertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Hello "+"<b>"+"World"+"</b>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
   @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
   AlertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Hello "+"<b>"+"World"+"</b>"));
}
```

For more details have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905107/1079901).

Comment: PS:Works for TextView, havn't checked for AlertDialog.

Comment: you can use HtmlCompat.fromHtml(string str , flag) where you can use HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY as the flag, so that you avoid os version checking

Answer (score 26):

This [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) describes how to add HTML formatting to resource strings.

```
<resources>
    <string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have &lt;b>%2$d new messages&lt;/b>.  
    </string>
</resources>
```

And do not forget to use: `Html.fromHtml`

```
AlertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.welcome_messages)));
```

This works for me

Comment: This one worked for me, should be tagged as the right answer

Answer (score 1):

In case if anyone wants to add only a single string:

```
<string name="abouttxt">&lt;b>Enter license key&lt;/b></string>
```

Add this line in your Alertdialog code.

```
dialog.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.abouttxt)))
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me, but I am required to use an older version of the API so I could not use `Html.fromHtml`. To bold part of the text for an `AlertDialog` I had to use a `SpannableString`.

```
String msgPart1 = getString(R.string.PartOneOfMessage);
SpannableString msg = new SpannableString(msgPart1 + " " + boldTextString + " " + getString(R.string.PartTwoOfMessage));
msg.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), msgPart1.length() + 1, msgPart1.length() + datumName.length() + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
AlertDialog.setMessage(msg);
```

I am not saying this is the best way, but it was the way that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<string name="abouttxt">"<b>Info</b>\ntexttxtxtxtxt"</string>
```

this works for me in xml