# Set text in Bold in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to make a part of message text in Bold in AlertDialog.

I tried:

adding `<b> </b> tag` in `strings.xml` but nothing positive.

i have also used `Html.fromHtml("<b>"+getString(R.string.ittformulanote)+"</b>")`

i have also been to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935692/how-to-set-part-of-text-to-bold-when-using-alertdialog-setmessage-in-android) but no positive result.

Below my Code:

```
 showDialog(getActivity(),"Sample",Html.fromHtml("<b>"+getString(R.string.ittformulanote)+"</b>")+"\n\n"+));



public static void showDialog(Context mContext, String Title,
            String Description) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        dialog.setTitle(Title);
//      dialog.setMessage((Html.fromHtml("<b>"+Description+"</b>")));
        dialog.setMessage(Description);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        //

        AlertDialog alert=dialog.create();
//      dialog.show();
        alert.show();


    }
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979821/how-to-make-part-of-the-text-bold-in-android-at-runtime

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan i don't have a textview. I want to set message in alertDialog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060991/why-doesnt-my-text-show-up-with-style-when-using-spannablestringbuilder

Answer (score 8):

This [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) describes how to add HTML formatting to resource strings.

Their example seems to help if you are having trouble with formatting strings:

Store your styled text resource as an HTML-escaped string:

```
<resources>
  <string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have &lt;b>%2$d new messages&lt;/b>.</string>
</resources>
```

In this formatted string, a  element is added. Notice that the opening bracket is HTML-escaped, using the < notation.

Comment: Just to be clear, you also need Html.fromHtml() in your Java code, in addition to escaping the < as described here. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: i checked lots of solutions about this but this is the excatly working solution.

Comment: This works for AlertDialog when used with
String content = getString(R.string.welcome_messages);
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     text = Html.fromHtml(content, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY );
  }else {
            text = Html.fromHtml(content);
        }

Answer (score 4):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+getString(R.string.ittformulanote)+"</b>"));
        builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Please Try this code..Its working fine

Comment: How do u say man????Instead of Html..Please give a string..and analyze the difference

Answer (score 1):

You need to set bold text in xml like:

```
<resource>
<string id="@+id/your_message">We are <b><i>so</i></b> glad to see you.</string>
</resources>
```

And call it at particular place where you want text in bold like:

```
Html.fromHtml("<b>"+getString(R.string.your_message)+"</b>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<string name="demoStr"><Data><![CDATA[ <b>ABC</b> ]]> </Data></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="welcome">Welcome to <b>Android</b>!</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Yes, the text is no where bold

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating my own textView in AlertDialog.Builder.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_text_view, null);
TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_custom_text_view);
textView.setText(message);
builder.setView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the title and message bold, you can do this.

```
showDialog(getActivity(),"Sample",Html.fromHtml("<b>"+getString(R.string.ittformulanote)+"</b>")+"\n\n"+));


public static void showDialog(Context mContext, String Title, String Description) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle(Title);

    // Pass description to placeholder string
    dialog.setMessage(
        (Html.fromHtml("<b>" + getString(R.string.message_placeholder, Description) + "</b>"))
    );

    dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });


    AlertDialog alert=dialog.create();
    alert.show();
}



<resources>
    <string name="ittformulanote">&lt;b>Bold text note&lt;/b></string>
    <string name="message_placeholder">&lt;b>%1$s&lt;/b></string>
</resources>
```