# How can I make specific text argument bold in android dialog fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, dialogfragment

I would like to make the message arguments text bold given the following string file.how can i make it?

code is given blow:

```
<string name="meter_reading_dialog_message">Current Reading: %s m³ \nPrevious Reading: %s m³ \nConsumption Reading: %s m³</string>

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val toCurrentReading =
            requireArguments().getString(CURRENT_READING)
        val toPreviousReading =
            requireArguments().getString(PREVIOUS_READING)
        val toConsumption =
            requireArguments().getString(CONSUMPTION)

        return AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.confirmation_reading))
            .setMessage(
                getString(
                    R.string.meter_reading_dialog_message,
                    toCurrentReading,
                    toPreviousReading,
                    toConsumption
                )
            )
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.deactivate_save) { _, _ ->
                targetFragment?.onActivityResult(targetRequestCode, Activity.RESULT_OK, null)
            }
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel) { _, _ ->
                targetFragment?.onActivityResult(targetRequestCode, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null)
            }
            .create()
    }
```

Comment: I would like to make the message arguments text bold given the following string file.                        <string name="meter_reading_dialog_message">Current Reading:   %s m³ \nPrevious Reading: %s m³ \nConsumption Reading: %s m³</string>

Comment: you want to set bold part of a string ? And wich part will be bold in this code can you mentioned it

Comment: I would want to set the three arguments in the .setMessage as bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this for your situation.

you first define a string with it.

```
val mystring = getString(
                    R.string.meter_reading_dialog_message,
                    toCurrentReading,
                    toPreviousReading,
                    toConsumption
                )
```

After that, you can set bold value like in this example.

[How to set part of text to bold when using AlertDialog.setMessage() in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935692/how-to-set-part-of-text-to-bold-when-using-alertdialog-setmessage-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```
fun boldText(text: String) : String {
  return Html.fromHtml(text)
}


println(boldText("<b>This text bold.</b> This text normal."))
```

output=> **This text bold.** This text normal.